# How to use the Google Search Tool to change address from root to subdomain?

Tags: google-search

Recently migrated to Heroku which forced me onto a sub domain (different story). How do I notify Google that my site is now at the www subdomain as opposed to the root domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of Google?

A new hostname is seen as almost an entirely new site by Google. This is why splitting your site up by subdomain is generally considered a terrible move.

Here's a Google checklist for starting up a new domain with old content:

- Add a new property to your Search Console (Property names are the hostname) - submit a sitemap and it'll index the new site.
- Set a 301 redirect on requests for the main site, which redirect them to the equivalent path on your subdomain. You can use your servers rewrite module for this.
- If you've successfully redirected then all the old links are valid. No need to change anything else.